# NSURLProtocol doesn't get complete NSURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlprotocol

***Problem***: I have my subclass of NSURLProtocol, but the `NSURLRequest` returned by `+canonicalRequestForRequest:` or the request returned by `-connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` are never passed to my URL protocol instance.

***Details***: In my subclass of `NSURLProtocol`, I implement the method `+canonicalRequestForRequest:` to add an HTTP header to the request. The header is added successfully, but when `-startLoading` is called on my URL protocol, `self.request` doesn't include that header.

Additionally, when `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` is called on the delegate of the `NSURLConnection`, whatever request is returned by that method never reaches my URL protocol instance either.

I think the problem lies in that `initWithRequest:cachedResponse:client:` is called before `+canonicalRequestForRequest:` or `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` are called, and the resulting requests from those 2 methods are never passed to my URL protocol instance after it has been `alloc`/`init`.

**Is this a bug in Apple's URL loading system?** Is there a workaround? Am I doing something wrong?

---

### Update on April 6, 2014

Here is some sample code. I set 2 headers: one in `-[APViewController connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:]` called `X-WillSendRequestTest` and the other one in `+[APURLProtocol canonicalRequestForRequest:]`. Neither one is in the `NSURLRequest` fetched by calling `self.request` within `-[APURLProtocol startLoading]`.

***APViewController.m*** (the delegate of NSURLProtocol)

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse {
    NSLog(@"Will send request: %@", request);

    NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [request mutableCopy];

    // This header will not be in self.request when fetched within the -[APURLProtocol start loading] method.
    [newRequest setValue:@"12345" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-WillSendRequestTest"];

    NSLog(@"New request: %@", newRequest);

    return newRequest;
}
```

***APURLProtocol.m***

```
@interface APURLProtocol () <NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
// Private properties
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLConnection *connection;
@end




@implementation APURLProtocol

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Init methods

- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request cachedResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse client:(id<NSURLProtocolClient>)client {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

    if ((self = [super initWithRequest:request cachedResponse:cachedResponse client:client])) {

    }

    return self;
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark dealloc

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

    [_connection cancel];
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Inherited class methods

+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), request);

    id requestIsHandled = [self propertyForKey:kAPURLProtocolHandledRequest inRequest:request];

    if (requestIsHandled == nil
            && ([request.URL.scheme caseInsensitiveCompare:@"http"] == NSOrderedSame
                    || [request.URL.scheme caseInsensitiveCompare:@"https"] == NSOrderedSame
                    || [request.URL.scheme caseInsensitiveCompare:@"ftp"] == NSOrderedSame)) {
                NSLog(@"YES");
                return YES;
            }

    NSLog(@"NO");
    return NO;
}


+ (NSURLRequest *)canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

    NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [request mutableCopy];
    // This header will not be in self.request when fetched within the -[APURLProtocol start loading] method.
    [newRequest setValue:@"12345" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CanonicalRequestTest"];

    return newRequest;
}


+ (BOOL)requestIsCacheEquivalent:(NSURLRequest *)aRequest toRequest:(NSURLRequest *)bRequest {
    NSLog(@"Request is cache equivalent:");
    NSLog(@"Request 1: %@", aRequest);
    NSLog(@"Request 2: %@", bRequest);

    return YES;
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Inherited instance methods

- (void)startLoading {
    NSLog(@"%@. Request: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.request);

    NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [[self request] mutableCopy];
    [[self class] setProperty:@"" forKey:kAPURLProtocolHandledRequest inRequest:newRequest];

    [self.connection cancel];

    self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:newRequest
                                                                                                        delegate:self
                                                                                        startImmediately:YES];
}
@end
```

***NSURLRequest+test.m*** (category to extend the description of NSURLRequest)

***Warning***: Do not do this at home. Do not override a method or property using categories. This is for quick debugging purposes only.

```
@implementation NSURLRequest (test)

- (NSString *)description {
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %p {URL: %@, Method: %@, Headers: %@, Data: %@",
                    NSStringFromClass([self class]), self, self.URL, self.HTTPMethod, [self allHTTPHeaderFields], dataString];
}

@end
```

Comment: One thing first: why are you adding your header in +canonicalRequestForRequest:? I wouldn't do this. It's easy to introduce bugs with this approach. Please take a look into the documentation about this method and what canonical means. Not saying this is the problem, but have you tried just returning the same request in this method and adding your header in the -startLoading method instead?

Comment: The method +canonicalRequestForRequest: is where you are supposed to canonicalize a request. From the documentation: "It is up to each concrete protocol implementation to define what 'canonical' means. A protocol should guarantee that the same input request always yields the same canonical form." As a matter of fact, in Apple's iOS example (CustomHTTPProtocol), they canonicalize requests by adding the Accept, Accept-Encoding and Accept-Language headers in that method.

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose of +canonicalRequestForRequest:, and that's why I mentioned it. The reason I said that is because according to the implementation, you *may* introduce a bug by actually creating a request that isn't canonical. That's why I wasn't saying for sure this is the problem, but it could be. I've seen Apple's example, but I've also seen this (http://eng.42go.com/customizing-uiwebview-requests-with-nsurlprotocol/) one some time ago that works well and it sets the header in the -startLoading method. So I'm trying to help reducing the possibilities of errors.

Comment: Have you ever tried putting them in the -startLoading method instead? It will be hard to investigate what the bug is without looking into the code, but at least if we remove some possibilities, it will be easier to spot any bug you may have.

Comment: @rocir I have added some sample code. And yes, the headers I currently add in `+canonicalRequestForRequest:` can be moved to `-startLoading`. However, my concern is why is the `NSURLRequest` returned by the methods `+canonicalRequestForRequest:` or `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` (`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` protocol) completely ignored and not forwarded to the `NSURLProtocol` subclass handling the connection?

Comment: @rocir Additionally, if I remove my `NSURLProtocol` subclass, the changes made in `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` (such as adding a header) are actually applied and seen by the server endpoint.

Comment: I don't know if this question is still relevant, but did you try checking in -[APViewController connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:] if the kAPURLProtocolHandledRequest property is set in newRequest? I was bit by this exact problem before.